# Поиск по БД по части строки.

Tags: jquery, php, запрос, mysql

Имеем автодополнение формы и бд с городами.
Помогите с реализацией поиска по таблице и передачей обратно скрипту списка.
Используется JQuery UI.

Comment: where строка like '%".часть строки."%'

Answer (score 1):

В jquery есть контрол с автодополнением [http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). Ему нужно передать список всех городов из БД.
Я думаю автодополнение лучше реализовывать на клиенте, если городов не очень много.